# The parameter can't have a value of null because of its type, after enabling non-nullable feature

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyPage({Key key}) : super(key: key); // error in this line

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container();
}
```

This code had no error before but now it's showing me

```
key can't have a value of null because of its type
```